# How to change URL in Wordpress according to taxonomy name

Tags: php, wordpress

When I wrote a taxonomy for my WP site I made a misstake writing the name:
www.mysite.com/**clubs**/milan
Clubs is the taxonomy name as shown below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );

function create_book_tax() {
register_taxonomy(
    'player_clubs',//taxonomy name
    array( 'teams'),//CP name
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Clubs' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'clubs' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_admin_column'    => true,
    )
);
}
```

Instead of having www.mysite.com/**clubs**/milan I would like to replace **clubs** into **games**

How can I do it?

Comment: Change clubs in this line `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'clubs' )` to *games*

Comment: ... and remember to flush permalinks (go into Permalinks section in CMS and hit save)

Comment: Hi naththedeveloper
Thanks for your answer. Your suggestion works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't worked with `wordpress` that match but I thing the solution is the bellow code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );
function create_book_tax() {
register_taxonomy(
    'player_clubs',//taxonomy name
    array( 'teams'),//CP name
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Clubs' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'games' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_admin_column'    => true,
    )
);
}
```

As the other users has point out, you have to [flush permalinks in wordpress](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/) after you made this change. Or simply type:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

after your php function call.

Comment: Hi George
Thanks for your answer and your suggestion. Your example works using the second option'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'games' ). After that, as suggested by naththedeveloper, the permalinks need to be flushed.